# How do I create a rosbuild overlay on a catkin workspace?

Tags: ros, catkin, overlay, ros-groovy, rosbuild

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I installed Groovy and created a brand-new catkin workspace according to [this tutorial](http://www.ros.org/wiki/catkin/Tutorials/create_a_workspace), and everything works fine so far. However,
I tried to overlay my old rosbuild-style (aka "dry") packages like this:

```
source $HOME/ros-groovy/devel/setup.bash
mkdir $HOME/ros-groovy-old
cd $HOME/ros-groovy-old
rosws init . /opt/ros/groovy
rosws set $HOME/path/to/my/packages
```

According to [REP-128](https://github.com/tfoote/rep/blob/workspaces/rep-0128.rst), I
can enable the overlay with `source $HOME/ros-groovy-old/setup.bash`. This lets me work with my dry packages, but it makes ROS forget about my catkin workspace. If I re-source `$HOME/ros-groovy/devel/setup.bash`, I can use my wet packages in the catkin workspace again, but I loose the dry packages in the rosbuild workspace.

I checked and it seems that both `setup.bash` overwrite the ROS_PACKAGE_PATH with their own values. But how can I make them aware of each other? The only documentation Google came up with told me that the overlay should Just Work(tm). What am I doing wrong?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/49825/how-do-i-create-a-rosbuild-overlay-on-a-catkin-workspace?/) by [roehling](https://answers.ros.org/users/798/roehling/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1951 on 2012-12-05

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This was a bug in rosws. update rosinstall (via-apt get) to 0.6.22, and run rosws regenerate in your rosbuild workspace. the changed setup.sh should now include your catkin packages in the ROS_PACKAGE_PATH.

EDIT: Sorry, did not read your question careful enough. REP128 is not correct (and still work in progress). A tutorial on how to have a rosbuild workspace on top of a catkin workspace is here:
http://ros.org/wiki/catkin/Tutorials/using_rosbuild_with_catkin

So what you have to do is when you create your rosbuild workspace, you tell rosws which catkin workspace you want to overlay (Else it cannot know). So instead of calling:

```
rosws init . /opt/ros/groovy
```

call

```
rosws init . $HOME/ros-groovy/devel/
```

The same can be done later with rosws merge, but at the risk of having the catkin workspace at the wrong place in the ROS_PACKAGE_PATH.

---

Originally posted by [KruseT](https://answers.ros.org/users/888/kruset/) with karma: 7848 on 2012-12-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [roehling](https://answers.ros.org/users/798/roehling/) on 2012-12-06**:
According to `dpkg -s python-rosinstall`, I already have version 0.6.22-1.

**Comment by [roehling](https://answers.ros.org/users/798/roehling/) on 2012-12-06**:
Thanks, that worked.

**Comment by [KruseT](https://answers.ros.org/users/888/kruset/) on 2012-12-06**:
rep will be updated: https://github.com/ros-infrastructure/rep/pull/11